# Dart Type definition

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm still new to dart, so here is the issue, I'm trying to use the `BottomNavigationBar` widget, to it we should have a list of widgets right?

I'm trying to also add a title to this list, so my list looks like this one:

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _pages = [
    const {'page': CategoriesScreen(), 'title': 'Categories'},
    const {'page': FavouritesScreen(), 'title': "Favourite"}
]
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget
```

So far I get this error:

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' of 'function result'

Here is the scaffold the reproduce the issue:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Meals'),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.category),
            label: 'Categories',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.star),
            label: 'Favourites',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I believe the issue here is with the type definition for this list, so how should I define it?

Comment: Remove the `as Widget`

Comment: I think this issue isnt from this snippet, try to check the other place.Can you include a minimal full scaffold that will reproduce the issue

Comment: @Georgina 
removing as widget does nothing actually

Comment: @YeasinSheikh 
I have edited the question to include the scaffold

Comment: Can you replace `CategoriesScreen` and `FavouritesScreen` with dummy text widget one by one, then you can find the real issue

Comment: @kyrolosmagdy Could you include the whole code not just the build method. I don't think that is where the error is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the declaration of the `_pages` to:

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _pages = [
  <String, dynamic>{
    'page': Container(),
    'title': 'Categories',
  },
  <String, dynamic>{
    'page': Container(),
    'title': 'Favourite',
  }
];
```

The same use:

```
 body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,
```

**Recommended solution**

I recommend you to create your custom model, e.g: "Screen" which will have following properties:

- page which is Widget type,
- title which is String type,

so:

```
class Screen {
  const Screen({
    required this.page,
    required this.title,
  });
  final Widget page;
  final String title;
}
```

then declare the list:

```
final List<Screen> _pages = [
  Screen(page: Container(), title: 'Categoris'),
  Screen(page: Container(), title: 'Favourite'),
];
```

and then use it:

```
 body:  _pages[_selectedPageIndex].page,
```

Comment: Creating Custom Model did the magic here for me, Thanks a lot